# if distance() < 20 line never executes

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a game in python where the user controls a turtle using the keyboard. An event is meant to occur when it reaches a point on the screen. This is an issue that occurs twice in the game. This is part of my code that's giving me trouble:

```
#user character
turt = turtle.Turtle()

bg = turtle.Screen()
bg.setup(width=600,height=700)

#identifying coordinate for 'treasure'
x1 = random.randrange(-280, 280)
y1 = random.randrange(-320, -20)
x2 = random.randrange(-280, 280)
y2 = random.randrange(-320, -20)
x3 = random.randrange(-280, 280)
y3 = random.randrange(-320, -20)
x4 = random.randrange(-280, 280)
y4 = random.randrange(-320, -20)
x5 = random.randrange(-280, 280)
y5 = random.randrange(-320, -20)

listofcoordinates = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4), (x5, y5)]
treasure = random.choice(listofcoordinates)

#user controls
def moveup():
    turt.setheading(90)
    turt.forward(10)
def movedown():
    turt.setheading(270)
    turt.forward(10)
def moveright():
    turt.setheading(0)
    turt.forward(10)
def moveleft():
    turt.setheading(180)
    turt.forward(10)
bg.onkeypress(moveright, "Right")
bg.onkeypress(moveleft, "Left")
bg.onkeypress(moveup, "Up")
bg.onkeypress(movedown, "Down")
bg.listen()

#issue
if turt.distance(treasure) < 20: #This line is never executed
    turt.goto(treasure)
    print("You found the treasure!!")
```

There's another part in the game where another turtle follows the user's turtle. When the following turtle reaches a (different) point on the screen, another event is supposed to occue. Again, the 'if' statement is never triggered.

```
#turtle that follows user character
badturt = turtle.Turtle()

health = 3
b = 5
while turt.distance(badturt) > 0:
    badturt.setheading(badturt.towards(turt))
    badturt.forward(b)

if badturt.distance(-25, 120) < 10:
    health = health - 1
    print("The health is down to", health)
    badturt.goto(0,0)
    b = b + 1
```

I assume I'm making the same error twice. I know this is probably a simple mistake, since I'm a beginner, but I can't seem to find anything wrong.

Comment: you only check the first if once, the second if is never / only once checked when you leave the while loop. You need to do this every time your turtle moves.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is never defined and never called (as it's never defined):

```py
def checkTreasureReached(turtle, treasure, dist):
    if turtle.distance(treasure) < dist:
        turtle.goto(treasure)
        print("You found the treasure!!")
```

Then you should call this function after a movement:

```
def checkTreasureReached(turtle, treasure, dist):
    #...

#user controls
min_distance = 20

def moveup():
    turt.setheading(90)
    turt.forward(10)
    checkTreasureReached(turtle, treasure, min_distance)

def movedown():
    turt.setheading(270)
    turt.forward(10)
    checkTreasureReached(turtle, treasure, min_distance)

def moveright():
    turt.setheading(0)
    turt.forward(10)
    checkTreasureReached(turtle, treasure, min_distance)

def moveleft():
    turt.setheading(180)
    turt.forward(10)
    checkTreasureReached(turtle, treasure, min_distance)
```

Or in your while loop:

```
min_distance = 20
while turt.distance(badturt) > 0:
    badturt.setheading(badturt.towards(turt))
    badturt.forward(b)
    checkTreasureReached(turt, treasure, min_distance)
```